# Who's devi Koutavi who shielded Banasura from Krishna?

Tags: shiva, krishna, devi, harivamsa

Koutavi (also identified as Vijaya) in Harivamsa tries to shield Banasura from Shri Krishna by standing before the Lord.

She even sheds her clothes and stands naked in front of Krishna, pleading for mercy.
Is she the personification of Shiva's trident Vijaya? Or is she another devi?
[image]

Comment: Kotavi is the kuladevi of Banasura.